# Java: Dealing with a lot of identical named classes in very long packages

Tags: java, coding-style

Following problem: A lot of **generated** Java classes that look like this:

```
com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version2.Message1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version3.Message1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version4.Message1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version5.Message1;
```

...

Each of these Message1 classes has a lot of nested subclasses or constants, e.g.

```
com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1.VERSION.VERSION_A_WITH_CHANGE_1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1.VERSION.VERSION_B;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1.Group1.SubGroupA.Format.MESSAGEFORMAT_1;
com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1.Group1.SubGroupA.Format.MESSAGEFORMAT_2;
```

...

The nesting becomes even deeper (up to 10 levels).
How do I deal with this? The code quickly becomes unreadable, because comparing to an enum value stretches over multiple lines...

Any ideas?

Comment: .. Using `import`?

Comment: @akuzminykh import doesn't help because of the identical class names in different packages.

Comment: You are using multiple versions at once?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes. have to deal with different protocol versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have an aliasing system. Therefore, no easy solution exists.

### Easy solution: Fix the generator

Whatever is generating this? Fix that. Make that not generate 'Message1' in a million packages, but something more useful, such as 'Message1V1', 'Message1V2', etcetera.

### Hard solution: Generate code

Alternatively, if you can't change either the generator code or the template data that the generator uses. You could write a code generator that does something like:

```
public final class Message1Constants {
    public static final Whatever_VERSION_is V1_VERSION = 
      com.company.project.lib.messages.version1.Message1.VERSION;
}
```

so that you can write:

```
import static Message1Constants.*;

...

int x = V1_VERSION.VERSION_B;
```

You could, of course, manually write this `M1Constants` class but that does mean you need to remember to update it, and given that the `Message1 classes are generated, you probably don't want that.

Thus, you'd have to ensure this class is, itself, generated.

Writing the generator is quite some effort, and will also complicate your build tooling a little bit. Annotation Processors can be used here (they are, effectively, a 'hook' into the compiler, they run during compilation). A big issue is that compilation runs are incremental, so the annotation processor cannot just 'gather constants' and 'generate a source file' - it needs to analyse the existing source file and leave intact any constants that were generated because of the existence of some input source file that is not part of this incremental run. Even if you know what you are doing this is a multi-day project at the very least.